# Why does "parallel --tty -Xj1 vim" hang?

Tags: jobs, interactive, tty, gnome-terminal, gnu-parallel

By issuing the following commands:

```
touch foo bar
echo foo bar | parallel --tty -Xj1 vim
```

The last command does not open the `foo` and `bar` files in the Vim editor but shortly afterwards prevents the current tab of the GNOME terminal from accepting any key presses such as `CTRL-C`, `CTRL-D` etc. To recover the current terminal tab must be closed via the 'X' button.

Any ideas how to make the last command work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a known bug introduced in 20141122. It is fixed in the git version and in version <20141022.